# How to prevent readonly fields data of my form?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-security

My application is a Spring MVC framework based. Using JSP for my form. Some users are modifying read-only fields of form by pressing F12 or by developer tools. How can I stop users from modifying readonly fields of my form? Actually, there are many forms and doing server-side validation by searching from the database at run time for those fields which are readonly in my form is not good for performance and a big task. I have found this issue recently and I want to understand how can I stop users from doing it. Thanks.

Comment: You can't prevent user from altering the attribute of your form. The best things you could do is not taking in considuration the values that are stored in your readonly field.

Comment: same as nicolas said,by the way you can use security like realm with the server to prevent the user from using submit methods if the user isnt authorized to do so.

Comment: If user alter data of my readonly fields, how will server check or how can I prevent the user from using submit button? I am using jboss for server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't rely on the client.**

That is, security on the client-side is not security.

Any security checks you do, or assumptions you make, on the client (aka HTML, javascript, etc) are irrelevant, and need to be performed on the server.
When the user submits the form, simply disallow any values the user is not authorized to.

1. The user can edit the HTML and put a custom input
2. On the client side he can edit the submit request
3. He can change the value of an existing *not-readonly* input